# How can I make custom dialogs angeled edges

Tags: android, dialog, customdialog

When I create my custom dialog it looks like this :
[image: dialog]

but I want it to look like this :
[image: dialog]

Answer (score 1):

Create a class which extends Dialog and inflate it your layout

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog
    {
        public CustomDialog (Context context)
        {
            //use this Theme, or any other theme you like
            super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom dialog and inflate your designed xml into it.

```
final Dialog yourDialog=new Dialog(context);
thumbnail_click.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own cutom layout for dialog as in the follwing link

[Custom dialog](http://blog.androgames.net/10/custom-android-dialog/)

[Custom Dialog PoPup](http://i.thiyagaraaj.com/articles/android-articles/customdialogboxpopupusinglayoutinandroid)

Answer (score 0):

You can always **inflate** your own custom dialog box layout.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, (ViewGroup)     findViewById(R.id.dialog_layout_root));
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
```

Comment: and how can I implement a button and a checkbox ? the code :final CheckBox check = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);  wont work

Comment: You should refer that as root_layout.findViewById, where root layout is the main layout that you have inflated.

Comment: how can I dismiss the dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't got an answer yet, here is a good toturial: [Toturial](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/55)

You vill need to make your own XML shape-style file, and use the corner function ex:

```
<corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />
```